# What tool could be used to develop multi-platform games with libGDX?

Tags: java, ide, game-development

Is there a tool that could be used out of the box with libGDX for developing multi-platform games on Mac and Windows with the possibility to target iOS and Android?

I tried NetBeans and Eclipse but the configuration process is slow and error prone in both. Most often than not all there is are outdated guidelines or tutorials if one is lucky, sometimes an entry in a forum or email list could help too, but in general the overall process is time consuming and excruciating.

Also having a crappy internet connection, I rather prefer something that has already all that’s needed for the development process, at least for the typical setup in the host platform (i.e. either Mac or Windows).

Answer (score 2):

The [JetBrains IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) community edition may well fit the bill in this instance, but for all of these you need to do the Gradle setup first, and then import. Personally, I've been using Eclipse and not had an issue since the libgdx setup was improved, but I can see why it would be problematic for someone who wasn't intimately aware of how Eclipse operates with non-standard projects.